# Отступы после изображения

Tags: html, css

Добрый день. Подскажите от куда берется и как убрать этот отступ после изображения перед фоновой полоской. Спасибо.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.line {
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/leopard_big_cat_predator_escape_71780_300x187.jpg" alt="">
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: @MedvedevDev а там вопрос и ответ оформлены хуже — я в поиске этот вопрос не смог найти, например. Лично я воздержусь от голосования за дубликат

Comment: @andreymal, может есть смысл подкорректировать тот вопрос, а не плодить новые с "правильной" формулировкой?

Comment: @MedvedevDev лично я тоже воздержусь, изменения слишком значительные надобны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что по умолчанию нижний край картинки внутри текста выравнивается по т.н. `baseline`. А это не нижний край строки, а вот так:

[image]

Вот это пустое пространство под нижнюю часть буквы `g` (а также `p`, `q` и прочие торчащие вниз буквы) и отображается под картинкой в вашем случае.

Убирается отступ очень просто: заменяем для картинки значение свойства CSS `vertical-align` на любое отличное от `baseline`. Например, на `top`, `middle` или `bottom` — смотря что лучше подходит для вашего конкретного случая.

```css
.myimg {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.line {
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<img class="myimg" src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/leopard_big_cat_predator_escape_71780_300x187.jpg" alt="">
<div class="line"></div>
```

<sup>(картинка честно стырена [отсюда](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/vertical-align/), там же можно почитать подробнее на английском)</sup>

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Вставьте display:flex или display:block в img:

```
img {
  display: flex;
}
```